# robocopy - how to copy from source to destination while the source is being copied to

Tags: robocopy

I have a source and a destination, i am trying to copy from source to destination using robocopy.

The catch is that I want to start robocopy as soon as i start copying files to a source. This means that the source will keep updating while I copy the source to a destination.

Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Comment: I don't think Windows Task scheduler has an option to trigger an action on directory size change.. You can schedule it to run a task on regular intervals

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at File System Watcher http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.110).aspx

Create an app that keeps on running in background, and checks for Directory size change, And whenever it changes, trigger a copy event.

Comment: thanks, i also need to sync a new source folder at the end of every day. any idea how to accomplish that aswell?

Comment: Yeah Windows Task Schedular, Just schedule a script that copies stuff from your source to destination, and create a task in the task schedular that executes the file after the time you want to execute it